# Loop through selected table rows with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have a table, containing a checkbox to select the whole row (or not).
This selection is done through JavaScript (JQuery) by setting a class attribute on the row.

```
function SelectRow(pRowID)
{
    $("#"+pRowID).toggleClass("selected");
}
```

Next step, I want to loop through all selected rows of the table (to extract data from it).
Apperently, when I want to loop through the table, there are no rows with the class attribute "selected".

```
    $("table tr.selected").each(function(){
        // get the data
    });
```

I finally found out what the problem is... obviously the JQuery script does not work on IE6. Problem is that IE6 is the only browser we have within the company, so it HAS to work on that one. No other browsers are allowed to be installed (that's why it took so long to found out the problem).

So if anyone has a solution to make this work on IE6, I'd be greatly thankful.

Comment: Greg, I thought so too. but the loop never returns anything. it does return all rows when I only have $("table tr"). The source of the page (after checking some lines) does not contain the class either.

Comment: The CSS is applied on the TR.

Comment: That would be a problem. I'm currently at the company, and the only thing we have to work with is IE6 (I know, don't say anything). We're not allowed to install any other browsers, so I cannot test it right now with FireBug :s But the row does get the CSS for the class "selected". So I assume it gets applied... unless it's only somewhere in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... found FireFox Lite which does it exactly by adding a JS script to your page. Anyway... looking at the html with the tool, the rows DOES have the class "selected" present. Though they are actually class="odd selected", since there are 2 classes applied on it.

Comment: I think the problem would be somewhere else. Sorry, can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working properly. Please have a look if this can help you.

The script is simple by clicking on td you can select row and clicking on **Down** and **Up** buttons you can transfer rows from upper table to lower and vice versa.

HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .selected{background-color:#ffeeee;color:#aaf;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid blue;width:200px;margin:5px;}
tr{background-color:#eeffee;color:ddaada;}
    span{border:1px solid #CC3300;background-color:#CC9900;color:#CC3300;
                   margin:5px;}
</style>

<table id="upper">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>first</td><td>row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>second</td><td>row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>third</td><td>row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>fourth</td><td>row</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>fifth</td><td>row</td></tr>
</table>

<span id="btnUp">Down</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="btnDown">Up</span>

<table id="lower">
    <tr><td>A</td><td>This</td><td>is</td><td>1</td><td>row</td></tr>
</table>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("table tr td").click(function(){
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("selected");
        });
        $("#btnUp").click(function(){
            var tl=$("table#lower");
            var tu=$("table#upper");            
            $("tr.selected", tu).each(function(){
                $(tl).append($(this).removeClass("selected"));
            });
        });
        $("#btnDown").click(function(){
            var tl=$("table#lower");
            var tu=$("table#upper");
            $("tr.selected", tl).each(function(){
                $(tu).append($(this).removeClass("selected"));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks to your 'working' example I was able to track back the steps and now it works with following line: $("table.result tr.selected").each(function(){...